# like operator syntax in sqlite with android

Tags: android

I'm developing with Android and I need to do a query with sqlite using the like operator and variables.

The piece of code I just try to modify is, the implementation of a database present at [this link.](http://saigeethamn.blogspot.it/2009/10/android-developer-tutorial-part-12.html)

So, I'm trying to do a query on the table created in the link in order to select just a name from a table. I'm doing like this:

```
Cursor c = sampleDB.rawQuery("SELECT FirstName, Age FROM " +
SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME + " where" +field+ " like %"+search+"%" , null);
```

where field and search are two variable defined above in this way:

```
final String field = "LastName";
final String search = "Makam";
```

If I execute the app in output, I should see a row with the name and age that I have selected in the query.But, I obtain nothing!!!

The `Logcat of Eclipse` shows :

```
sqlite returned: error code = 1,msg = near "like": syntax error.
```

But I'm pretty sure the syntax it' s correct. Could someone help me?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

use this way:

```
Cursor c = sampleDB.rawQuery("SELECT FirstName, Age FROM " +
SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME + " where " +field+ " like '%"+search+"%'" , null);
```

---

### Edited: create function

```
public Cursor getSearch(String SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME, String field,
            String search) {
        SQLiteDatabase sampleDB = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor c = sampleDB.rawQuery("SELECT FirstName, Age FROM "
                + SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME + " where " + field + " like '%" + search
                + "%'", null);
        return c;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you!!! In your way it works. And now if i want to implement a function that do the query of the name how I have to proceed?

Comment: I want to do a function to do the query of the name as above. So in this way:

Comment: function namefunction (parameters)

Answer (score 3):

Looks to me as though you might be missing a space between `WHERE` and `field`.

Answer (score 3):

```
selection.append(column_name).append(" like ?");
                    selectionArgs = new String[]{"%" + mCategoryName + "%"};
                    db.query(TABLE_URI,null,selection.toString(),selectionArgs,null);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
final String field = "LastName";
final String search = "Makam";

String query = "SELECT FirstName, Age FROM " +
SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME + " where " +field+ " like '%+search+%'";

Cursor c = sampleDB.rawQuery(query,null);
```

All the best!